# Techniques (tools) to convert temporal logic (CTL,CTL* or LTL) to μ-calculus formulae

Tags: logic, simulation, linear-temporal-logic, computation-tree-logic, mu-calculus

Suppose one wants to use a μ-calculus model checker, but specify things in temporal logics, which is easier (more intuitive). Is there a technique (even better, a tool) that automatically translates formulae in any of these logics (CTL,CTL* or LTL) to the μ-calculus?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You may find an answer or at least relevant references in the article
[A linear translation from LTL to the first-order modal $\mu$-calculus](http://www.win.tue.nl/~jfg/articles/CSR-10-09.pdf).